# What capacity of heat pump is needed for a residence near Phoenix, Arizona?

Tags: hvac

What size heat pump is needed for a 1,924 sq.ft. home 35 miles northwest of Phoenix, Arizona?

The home has 6" insulated exterior walls, stucco exterior, 10' ceilings, southern exposure and "average" number of windows. Construction is in the framing stage.

Answer (score 1):

The Number of Windows and sliding glass doors also play into the calculation, it sounds like you have good insulation, but that area gets much hotter than where I live. Some of the calculators on line are focused on energy savings and provide questionable advice in my opinion. The best way to find out would be to talk to neighbors with similar sized homes. Ask about Thier unit size, power consumption and if the units cool well when the temp gets into the 100's . If they want to size the unit on square footage alone (unless the company can show a very similar home) find another company because Windows and doors add a large cooling load even if double Payne. Many years ago before I got my HVAC license I had a 2900 sf home with 26 Windows and 3 sliding glass doors. The company recommended a 3.5 ton unit, I thought that would be two small after talking to a neighbor with a similar home that had a 4 ton and said it was not enough. I had a 5 ton installed and on the hottest days that was not enough to keep the home at 78F.

Answer (score 1):

It is not simply a matter of location, type of structure, and size.

- How much sun exposure is there?
- What type of insulation?
- What type of roof?
- What is the elevation of the lot?
- What is the orientation of the house to the sun?
- How many people are normally present?
- How much heat generating activities are performed:  cooking, showering, electronics, lighting, indoor hot tubs, etc.
- How often are windows, curtains, and doors kept open?

While some of these issues are usually ignored and replaced by a rule-of-thumb average, they are potential issues for non-average homes.

Given the expense of a cooling system, it is well worth getting quotes from at least three HVAC contractors based on assessment from an on-site inspection.  That way they can consider all the relevant factors.  Also, if they miscalculate, then you can hang them from a hook until they make the system function properly *at their expense* if they made a mistake.